# Custom layout of button in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to custom layout of a button?
I want to create a button with layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="aaa" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="bbb" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set your LinearLayout as clickable and viola, you've got a button.

Comment: If you found one of our answers useful, please upvote & accept one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and proper way is to create a subclass of Button, and inflate your custom XML layout in the constructor. This way the custom button is reusable.

More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

Answer (score 0):

Give that `LinearLayout` an id. Add an `onClickListener` to that. and you got a button with that layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom "button" from a View element by adding in xml to your view `android:onClick="myFunction"` and in code declare your function `void myFunction(View v){ .. }`.

Or declare click listeners on your View in code

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearButton); 
myLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    myFunction(v);
}
});

void myFunction(View v){
//do something awesome here
}
```

This is the simplest way I think. Or you can extend a Button class, add new XML styles for different button states (activated, highlighted, normal) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html